# How to provide access to Jenkins to the web

Tags: jenkins

I've installed Jenkins on my mac via homebrew.
I've real ip.
How can i have access outside local network/mac? For example from other location?

Answer (score 1):

You can use portforwarding on your router if you have a fixed IP from your isp
where you forward every connection from externalip:portnumber to internalip:portnumber.

Where internal ip is the ip of your mac and the portnumber is the portnumber to which your jenkins listens.

If you dont have a fixed ip you would need to use a dns provider like http://www.noip.com/